# scala chaining Trys with managed resource that needs finally/close()

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

For practice, I've gotten some straightforward JDBC stuff from like 100 lines down to this, but it won't typecheck. Any ideas? Better approaches?

```
def withResultSet[T](sql: String, f: ResultSet => T)(implicit info: ConnectionInfo): Try[T] = {
    for {
      conn <- Try(connect(info))
      stmt <- Try(conn.createStatement()) orElse { case err: SQLException => {conn.close(); err} }
      results <- Try(stmt.executeQuery(sql)) orElse { case err: SQLException => { conn.close(); stmt.close(); err }}
    } yield f(results)
  }
```

and my error is

```
 missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: scala.util.Try[?]
      stmt <- Try(conn.createStatement()) orElse { case err: SQLException => {conn.close(); err} }
                                                 ^
```

Comment: The sweet spot in Scala is somewhere between the LOC in Java and the point where it doesn't type check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that `Try` is the right tool to dispose of resources once they are no longer needed. At least I cannot see an obvious way to do it. You may want to look at https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm. Then your code may look like this:

```
def withResultSet[T](sql: String, f: ResultSet => T)(
                     implicit info: ConnectionInfo): ManagedResource[T] = for {
  conn <- managed(connect(info))
  stmt <- managed(conn.createStatement()) 
  results <- managed(stmt.executeQuery(sql))
} yield f(results)
```

You can keep using map or flatMap (or for comprehension) to work with possibly other resources and at the end you can get an `Option` or an `Either` out of it and at the same time close everything that needs to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can split your function into different parts, one for each resource type, and use it together with a separate resource manager trait.

The generalized resource manager (can be used with files etc. as well):

```
trait ResourceManager {
  def withResource[T <: {def close()}, R](resource: T)(code: (T) => R): R = {
    try {
      code(resource)
    } finally {
      import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
      resource.close()
    }
  }
```

is mixed into something like this

```
class Db extends ResourceManager {
  private def getConnection = ...

  def withConnection[T](f: (Connection) => T): T = {
    withResource(getConnection) {
      conn =>
        f(conn)
    }
  }

  def withStatement[T](f: (Statement) => T): T = {
    withConnection {
      conn =>
        withResource(conn.createStatement()) {
          stmnt =>
            f(stmnt)
        }
    }
  }

  def withResultSet[T](selectSqlCmd: String)(f: (ResultSet) => T): T = {
    withStatement {
      stmnt => {
        withResource(stmnt.executeQuery(selectSqlCmd)) {
          rs =>
            f(rs)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which stacks the resources, and gives entry points at each level.

On top of this another level

```
  def mapResultSet[T, C <: Iterable[T]](selectSqlCmd: String)
                              (f: (ResultSet) => T)
                              (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, C]): C = {
    withResultSet(selectSqlCmd) {
      rs =>
        val builder = cbf()
        while (rs.next()) {
          builder += f(rs)
        }
        builder.result()
    }
  }
```

Each method goes only one step further down, the `for` comprehension is decomposed into separate functions, and the `Try` does not interfere.

Use it like this:

```
val db = new Db()
val result = db.mapResultSet("select * from pg_user")(rs => rs.getString(1))
```

to read from the database in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

`recoverWith` is what i needed; you don't actually need to recover you can just rethrow.

```
def withResultSet[T](sql: String, f: ResultSet => T)(implicit info: ConnectionInfo): Try[T] = {
    for {
      conn <- Try(connect(info))
      stmt <- Try(conn.createStatement()) recoverWith { case err => {conn.close(); Failure(err)} }
      results <- Try(stmt.executeQuery(sql)) recoverWith { case err => { conn.close(); stmt.close(); Failure(err) }}
    } yield f(results)
  }
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, you aren't closing connection and statement if you succeed...